# Is it possible to configure an RDS instance as the slave of my current MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, rds

I want to launch an RDS instance, to act as the slave of my current MySQL server.
My current MySQL server is in production environment, but we plan to have a new feature running on EC2+RDS, and the new feature is read-only. We need to replicate part of the database to RDS.

One option is to use a periodic job to replicate data from current MySQL to RDS, but I'm still wondering if it is possible to leverage the master/slave replicating functionality of MySQL itself.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it cant be done.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, there is no way to use MySQL's master/slave replication features to make an RDS system a slave of another system, either system.  With RDS MySQL versions 5.1 and 5.5 one can only make a new read only replica from an existing MySQL RDS server that has the same MySQL version.  With RDS MySQL 5.6 one can make an external slave of the RDS master.  However, one cannot do the reverse, where an external server or different RDS MySQL can be the master for an RDS MySQL 5.6 slave.

References: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/amazon-rds/page/2/ (regarding MySQL 5.6 support)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html (regarding RDS MySQL 5.6 replicating to a non RDS MySQL 5.6 slave).